# Parameter becoming zero somewhere

Tags: xcode, parameter-passing, objective-c++

Something really weird is happening: when I call foo(100*1.0f), somewhere along the line that becomes 0. To verify I put a breakpoint on foo(), and it indeed is zero and it indeed gets called with 100*1.0f. The code is in Obj-C++.

Here is the calling function in XCode's GDB frontend, as you can see, score*scoreMultiplier is 100.
[Calling Function http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/1109/screenshot20100502at135.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/1109/screenshot20100502at135.png)

```
void JNPP1PGameController::addScoreToPlayer(NSInteger score) {
    if(!gameOver){
        JNLogString(@"Adding score(%d*%f) to player", score, scoreMultiplier);
        [player addScore: score*scoreMultiplier];
        [wrapper setShouldNotify];
        [wrapper notify];
    } else {
        JNLogString(@"Not adding score(%d*%f) because GAME IS OVAR", score, scoreMultiplier);
    }
}
```

And here is the called function in XCode's GDB frontend, here _score is 0.
[Called Function http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/1109/screenshot20100502at135.png](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/1109/screenshot20100502at135.png)

```
- (void) addScore:(NSInteger) _score {
    score += _score;
    JNLogString(@"Player can has %d points.. HURRAY!!!", score);
}
```

Comment: Tagging a question "mistery" will not help you get views or answers. In the future, try to tag questions properly.

Comment: Sorry Oded, I couldn't find popular tags to match them. Thanks for adding them.

Comment: Please post the code as text rather than as images.

Comment: You have some warnings left in your code (the yellow explanation mark signs). You should resolve these first.

Comment: @Banang: The pictures are to show the values of the variables at runtime, I'll add the code in a minute.

@swegi: I cannot resolve the warning, but it may be the cause of the problem, the warning is that it cannot find the method for setScore: .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was fixed by changing the calling code to this:

```
void JNPP1PGameController::addScoreToPlayer(NSInteger score) {
    if(!gameOver){
        JNLogString(@"Adding score(%d*%f) to player", score, scoreMultiplier);
        NSInteger _score = score*scoreMultiplier;
        JNLogString(@"This is the case: %d", _score);
        [player addScore: _score];
        [wrapper setShouldNotify];
        [wrapper notify];
    } else {
        JNLogString(@"Not adding score(%d*%f) because GAME IS OVAR", score, scoreMultiplier);
    }
}
```

I assume now something went wrong with casting to a undefined (I got a "method not found" warning) parameter type.